# Conseguir URL de una imagen subida en Firebase Storage

Tags: firebase, xamarin, xamarin.android, storage

Estoy intentando cargar en mi aplicación Android una imagen que tengo almacenada en Firebase Storage, pero no consigo el URL de la imagen correctamente. 
Estoy recibiendo "com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@81d764c" en vez del URL completo a la imagen que me permita cargarla.
Estoy utilizando Xamarin (C#) para diseñar mi aplicación, adjunto el código:

```
private StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.Instance.Reference;

protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.hoteles);

        imageView1 = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView1);

        storageReference.Child("Hoteles/hotel1.jpg").GetDownloadUrl().AddOnCompleteListener(this);
    }

public void OnComplete(Task task)
    {
        if (task.IsSuccessful)
        {
            String url = task.ToString();
            ImageService.Instance.LoadUrl(url)
             .Retry(3, 200)
             .DownSample(500, 500)
             .Into(imageView1);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Imagenes no cargadas");
        }
    }
```

Espero que podáis ayudarme, muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Me parece que te falta codigo. Le pasas una task como parametro, y si esta bien le queres hacer toString. a la misma. Mostra el codigo completo, quien manda ese parametro.

Comment: La solución va como respuesta en lA zona de abajo

Comment: Yo estoy en la mismas. Alguien puede ayudarnos?